# Share Session between subdomains, devise authentication Completed 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, session-cookies, session-store

I have 2 ruby rails apps, each has a devise gem for authentication, my goal is to implement simple SSO (single sign-out), using shared sessions.

one of them with `public.admin.com` and the other with `private.admin.com` 
I am using the following configurations :

### session_store.rb

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_shared_admin_session', domain: '.admin.com', tld_length: 2
```

### config/secrets.yml

I also use the same `secret_key_base` value in both applications

### devise.rb

```
config.stretches = 1

config.pepper = ''
```

### application.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :hybrid
```

I can sign in for one of them and the session is open once I open the other domain `Completed 401 Unauthorized` is returned and the opend session is closed and sign out from the first domain.

I've tried with using `domain: 'admin.com'`, `domain: :all`,and `..session_store :redis_store..`, but the same result always.

can anyone please help me find the problem, or suggest a better solution, I will be thankful.

Comment: one is using Rails4 and the other is Rails5, I am not sure is this the problem or is a test issue

Answer (score 2):

when you want to share session between domains you would want to do is edit your **config/initializers/session_store.rb** file to look like this:

```
APPNAMEGOESHERE::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_tourlyapp_session', :domain => "your_domain_name.com"
```

The trick here is the `:domain` option. What this does is sets the level of the TLD (top-level domain) and tells Rails how long the domain is. The part you want to watch out for here is that if you set `domain: :all` like is recommend in some places, it simply won’t work unless you’re using localhost. :all defaults to a TLD length of 1, which means if you’re testing with Pow (myapp.dev) it won’t work either because that is a TLD of length 2.

I hope that this helps you out

Comment: thank you for replaying, when I open browser cookies I can see the cookie with key `_shared_admin_session ` is mapped to domain `.admin.com ` for both domains tabs so, I am really not sure if the session is really shared for( reading/ and writing) on it

Comment: you can test it with `lvh.me:3000` and `admins.lvh.me:3000` see if its working properly for you

Comment: is it normal to recieve 401 Unauthorized, rails server logger `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

Comment: Can anyone please answer @Eftikhar as I have the same problem

Comment: Hello mr.maheshwsri you can check the note I added as answer, make sure that the users read from same db:table

Comment: Yes!! Thank you @MZaragoza 

I spent the last few hours trying to debug my own application on production.

If somebody else reads this, perhaps it would help to give some details:

-I am building an app that can have an unlimited number of subdomains. In development, I had my session_store config with `domain: :all` and am using Pow - it works fine locally. On pushing to production on a Heroku site, posting any form (though in my particular case, a User Registration Devise Form) would result in `Can't verify CSRF token`. Setting my domain to be `domain: "my-app.herokuapp.com"` fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was simple.

the problem was in use 2 different DBs, after unifying admin table things worked fine.